# Android : Fade animation on imageView and scroll became possible over ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

I would lile to reproduce this animation :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5uiJlSSk9dZNW1tMENkZGNjMWM/edit?usp=sharing

When the user scroll, it produce a fade in animation on imageview and scroll become possible to top.

Is there an existing library which do this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You might find this link interesting, it partially answers your question (at least, for its most complicate part: the FAST BLUR): http://trickyandroid.com/advanced-blurring-techniques/

Comment: Ok thanks for the blur effect. And how to allow to scroll on the imageview ?

Comment: See the reference page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: Did you ever find a solution on this? I would like to build this function too

Comment: @wawanopoulos would you please answer your question if did that?